# sqlite: globbing in a list of patterns

Tags: sqlite

I have a list of `GLOB` patterns (of unknown length), and would like to `SELECT` all entries that match *any* of the patterns.

The naive approach would be:

```sql
SELECT name, age
WHERE name GLOB 'John*' OR name GLOB 'Mar*'
;
```

However, this seems extraordinarily clumsy (esp. if there are many patterns).

When doing an exact match, I can use the `IN` keyword, like so:

```sql
SELECT name, age
WHERE name IN ('John', 'Mary')
;
```

So I wonder, whether I can do something similar with `GLOB`, e.g. like this (obviously non-working example):

```sql
SELECT name, age WHERE name GLOB IN ('John*', 'Mar*');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a CTE that returns all the patterns that you want and in the main query use `EXISTS` to check if there is any match:

```
WITH cte(pattern) AS (VALUES ('John*'), ('Mar*'))
SELECT t.*
FROM tablename t
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM cte c WHERE t.name GLOB c.pattern);
```

`EXISTS` returns as soon as it finds the 1st match and does not need to check all the patterns.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=9b54126d33b14e023decd4ff1d6ed8b7).